# I want to find the average crowd numbers for specific time slot in a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset of fixtures for a football game that contains the following variables:
-Day the game was played
-Time the game was played (7:40pm, 3:35pm etc)
-Crowd numbers
-Home team
-Away team

I only have about 30 rows of data from one specific season, and I want to group the timeslots as close as I can to: Friday nights, Saturday Afternoon, Saturday Nights, Sunday Afternoon, Sunday Evening. From there I want to find the average crowds per time slot i.e sunday afternoon games. There are a range of start times and I want to as I mentioned group them to a more generalised start time. Any help?

```
##Converted data frame into more specific days of the week:

friday <- new_data[new_data$Day == 'Friday',]

saturday <- new_data[new_data$Day == 'Saturday',]

sunday <- new_data[new_data$Day == 'Sunday',]``

##Then found the mean for each day as a whole.`friday <- as.numeric(friday$Crowd)
mean(friday)`
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `dplyr::case_when` to define a variable with the timeslot category,  then `... |> summarize(mean_crowd = mean(Crowd), .by = timeslot_category)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

set.seed(0)

# create the toy dataset
df <- tibble(
  Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = "day"),

  # pick a random time between 11am and 11pm
  Time = hms(sample(0:59, size = 365, replace = TRUE), sample(0:59, size = 365, replace = TRUE), sample(11:23, size = 365, replace = TRUE)),

  # random crowd sizes
  home_crowd = sample(10000:20000, size = 365, replace = TRUE),
  away_crowd = sample(10000:20000, size = 365, replace = TRUE)
)


df %>% 
  mutate(Day = weekdays(Date),
         Period = case_when(
           Time < as_hms("12:00:00") ~ "Morning",
           Time < as_hms("16:30:00") ~ "Afternoon",
           Time < as_hms("19:00:00") ~ "Evening",
           TRUE ~ "Night"
         )) %>%
  group_by(Day, Period) %>%
  summarise(home_crowd = mean(home_crowd),
            away_crowd = mean(away_crowd))
```